# How to properly take and skip in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I want to return objects in two parts: first 5 and rest of them. I've tried the following:

```
$firstFive = Category::take(5)->get(); // this works.

$theRest = Category::skip(5)->take(5)->get(); // this works

$theRest = Category::take('THE REST')->skip(5)->get(); // of course not working
```

I know I can just enter a very large number in the take() to get the rest of them, but is there a way that takes exactly the rest of the objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that the `id` field is your primary key and has the `type` of `INT/BIGINT` and here you can use the maximum number for an `INT` type `4294967295` and `BIGINT` type  `18446744073709551615` so there is no chance to exceed the number of rows in a table that a particular type (`INT/BIGINT`) can have their maximum value. [MySQL Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html).

Also, the `MyISAM` engine (default) can store by default `2^32` rows. That's `4,294,967,296` rows. That could be extended to `2^64` using `--with-big-tables` option, so it'll support up to `2^64` rows per table.

The `InnoDB` storage engine doesn't have a limit on the number of rows, but it has a limit on table size of `64TB`. How many rows fits into this depends on the size of each row.

From `MySql` [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set. SO, you may use following to retrieve all rows from the 6th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,18446744073709551615;
```

Since you asked for exact numbers of rows then you may always use the `count(*) - offset` but `IMO` you don't need this and can avoid the count query.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a stupidly high value into `take` and it should work. I don't know of any other way. Leaving the `take` call out does not work, as it generates SQL like this:

```
/* MyModel::skip(2)->lists('id'); */
select `id` from `table` offset 2
```

And MySQL (at least) needs a `LIMIT` with an `OFFSET`.

```
/* MyModel::take(9999999)->skip(2)->lists('id'); */
select `id` from `table` limit 9999999 offset 2
```

It's hardly elegant though. Also it's probably worth investigating the maximum number that can be passed to `LIMIT` if you were to use this method to avoid edge cases when your DB is huge!

Comment: agreed, my use case only need a relatively large number and it should work. just wondering if the ridiculously high number will break the database when the table is huge...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that. I don't see why it'd be any worse than doing a non-limited `SELECT`, right?